# How to extract correct owner permission by tar?

Tags: file-permissions, tar

I want to pack specific some sub-directories contents, and extract them with original permission. In the following sample, it extract the directory `a` with wrong permission, I prefer it keep the same as original `foo`.  How to do it? What's parameter should I add to tar when archive or extract?

create test sample files :

```
foo ~/tmp $ mkdir -p a/b ; touch a/f1 a/b/f2
```

create archive file :

```
foo ~/tmp $ tar cf a.tar a/b
```

show tar file content :

```
foo ~/tmp $ tar tvf a.tar
drwxr-xr-x foo/op           0 2018-05-11 10:33 a/b/
-rw-r--r-- foo/op           0 2018-05-11 10:33 a/b/f2
```

extract with `root` user :

```
foo ~/tmp $ mkdir c
foo ~/tmp $ sudo tar -C c -xpf a.tar
foo ~/tmp $ find c -ls
  4743788      4 drwxr-xr-x   3  foo     op           4096 May 11 10:34 c
  4743789      4 drwxr-xr-x   3  root     root         4096 May 11 10:34 c/a
  4743790      4 drwxr-xr-x   2  foo     op           4096 May 11 10:33 c/a/b
  4727961      0 -rw-r--r--   1  foo     op              0 May 11 10:33 c/a/b/f2
```

What I expect is

```
  4743789      4 drwxr-xr-x   3  foo     op         4096 May 11 10:34 c/a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the archive into two steps, the first step archive as previous

```
tar cf a.tar a/b
```

The second step to append the directory without recursion

```
tar -rf a.tar --no-recursion a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a correct behavior.  Your `a.tar` does not contain directory `c/a` so it has to be created during the unpacking.  That is done under context of the user you are unpacking the archive with - *root*.

The tar option `-p` does preserve the rights to directories but only the existing in the archive.

Note: I'm unpacking it with user *smalltalk*.

### Option when you have already created archive and want to remove files from already created archive

I think you could pack all with:

```
tar cf a.tar a
```

which would then produce

```
tar tvf a.tar 
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/
-rw-rw-r-- smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/f2
-rw-rw-r-- smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/f1
```

Then you can simply delete the directories/files you don't want in this case `a/f1`:

```
tar -vf a.tar --delete a/f1
```

You will get:

```
tar tvf a.tar 
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/
-rw-rw-r-- smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/f2
```

Since now the directory `a/` is part of the packed file you will get correct result when unpacking:

```
find c -ls
149236    0 drwxrwxr-x   3 smalltalk smalltalk       14 May 11 10:14 c
17208669    0 drwxrwxr-x   3 smalltalk smalltalk       14 May 11 10:01 c/a
36340903    0 drwxrwxr-x   2 smalltalk smalltalk       15 May 11 10:01 c/a/b
36333667    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 smalltalk smalltalk        0 May 11 10:01 c/a/b/f2
```

### **First Edit - Second option** -- exclude before packaging

Is to create a `tar` file without the directory in the first place with `--exclude` option:

For example:

```
tar cf a.tar a --exclude=a/f1
```

Which would create:

```
tar tvf a.tar 
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/
-rw-rw-r-- smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/f2
```

Then the extracted directory would have correct rights.

### **Second Edit** - adding top most directory

- based on comment (many files) - adding directory after the archive has been already created

If you have many files I think the best solution is to add the directory to your already created archive.

You would then create the file as you did in your question:

```
tar cf a.tar a/b
```

Then you would add the top directory (`--no-recursion` option excludes the sub-directories):

```
tar -rvf a.tar --no-recursion a/
```

You will then get file with the added directory:

```
tar tvf a.tar 
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/
-rw-rw-r-- smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/b/f2
drwxrwxr-x smalltalk/smalltalk 0 2018-05-11 10:01 a/
```

Then you will get correct extraction:

```
find c -ls
68333351    0 drwxrwxr-x   3 smalltalk smalltalk       14 May 11 11:01 c
87520961    0 drwxrwxr-x   3 smalltalk smalltalk       14 May 11 10:01 c/a
149236    0 drwxrwxr-x   2 smalltalk smalltalk       15 May 11 10:01 c/a/b
824154    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 smalltalk smalltalk        0 May 11 10:01 c/a/b/f2
```

Comment: This solution seems require more extra work to specify all exclude files. I just simplified my example, in fact there are many directories and files.

Comment: @DanielYCLin I see, I'll edit my answer with what I think is best solution.